# How to suggest object Properties in JS?

Tags: javascript, object

Well, I'm building a library and there is a function that has two parameters (an element and an object). The object works as a "configurator" of the element and obviously its properties have already been declared, the user just needs to put the name of the specific property and the value he wants. The question is, how can a suggestion of the property name appear before typing the full name?

ex:

[image]

my code:

```
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
sudo(h1, {
  preReveal: "",

});
```

(in this case, I want to suggest preReveal)

Comment: I think you're asking about [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript). VSCode has built in "types" for native JavaScript objects, which is how it knows what properties you might need in the screenshot provided. You can do a similar thing by writing TypeScript over JavaScript.

Comment: The thing is, the suggest its only available because of vscode algorithm or this can be made through Javascript/typescript?

Comment: It *is* driven by TypeScript, and yes, you can do the same.